# Panel with multiple forms, choose top most with button

Tags: c#, panel, layer, subform

SO i have a main menu with buttons down the side and a panel which is my "main display area" (panelactive).

When i click a button for a form to fill the panelactive i need the relating form to be displayed initiated and displayed top-most.
if it is active already i want it just to come to the TOP.

I had this code

```
Form g = Application.OpenForms["frmpackmenu"];

        if (g == null)
        {
            frmpackmenu frmpackmenu = new frmpackmenu(topack, tocheck, total);
            frmpackmenu.TopLevel = false;
            panelactive.Controls.Add(frmpackmenu);
            frmpackmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            frmpackmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            frmpackmenu.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            g.Show();
        }
```

But the issue here is that each form doesn't "hide" after the new form is called to fill the panel.

I did try VISIBLE which worked.. however it only works once the forms have been initaited.. however i dont want all forms initaited on startup as most likely only one form is going to be used by the user and i have a selection of 6, one of which is quite memory heavy.

SO i need to:

1. Check if initiated
2. If not, initiate and move to top
3. If it is, just show it and hide the other initiated form so THAT doesnt have to reload later..

I have tried and i just can't wrap my head around how i can check all forms if they are there as well as make visible or not etc.

Or am i doing this all completely wrong??

Thansk for advice.
Gangel

Is doing a case statement and then doing this for ever case what i need to do??

```
if (collectmenu == null)
                {
                    frmcollectmenu frmcollectmenu = new frmcollectmenu();
                    frmcollectmenu.TopLevel = false;
                    panelactive.Controls.Add(frmcollectmenu);
                    frmcollectmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    frmcollectmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                    frmcollectmenu.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    collectmenu.Visible = true;
                }
                if (packmenu != null)
                {
                    packmenu.Visible = false;
                }
                if (checkmenu != null)
                {
                    checkmenu.Visible = false;
                }
```

**Update 1**:
Converted my forms to Usercontrols as recommended.

I now cant seem to get oCon to NOT be nul.  It seems to not identify that the control already exists!

```
UserControl oCon = (from UserControl uc in panelactive.Controls where uc.GetType() == typeof(UserControl) && uc.Name == "frmpackmenu" select uc).FirstOrDefault();
        if (oCon == null)
        {
            frmpackmenu frmpackmenu = new frmpackmenu(topack, tocheck, total);
            panelactive.Controls.Add(frmpackmenu);
            frmpackmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            frmpackmenu.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            oCon.BringToFront();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use UserControls for different work instead of forms. You can easily show/hide in panels.

Comment: SO each "menu" is a user control? Is that then loaded into the panel? Ive tried to learn about user controls but dont fully understand

Comment: Have you tried [form].BringToFront();?

Comment: When you need some sort of reusable functionality, and have to use in dynamic way, UserControls would be better choice. You can add/remove dynamically, or just add all at once, and set visible true/false when needed.

Comment: thanks ill look into it now.

Comment: Is there an easy of making the 6 forms i have into usercontrols? or i have to recreate all?  Is just adding : Usercontrol in the class name all i need?

Comment: It needs to be re-created all. But for now, you may want to continue with forms till you get some time space to fix later. At the moment, I did not clearly understand what exactly is the problem. Is there visibility issue?

Comment: How do i make user control TOP above other user controls in a panel? That is my question.

Comment: There will be function like BringToFront(), but it will not be the issue, you can just hide all user controls, and show on the required one.

Comment: how can i hide all?  Some have no been loaded yet, so if i do
frmpack.hide() it will error as there is no instance of frmpack yet

Comment: @GlennAngel you want a user control solution? I have one ready to go, but want to make sure you're ok with UCs so it doesn't get downvoted.

Comment: @Aaron yes i want to use whatever you recommend. I jsut want to be able to use a button to show a form/usercontrol then click another buttton and another onject will take its place BUT the original one is not lost and can be called back later.

Comment: @Aaron Apologies i didnt see your response from 25 mins ago, it didnt come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserControl solution. This will test if your panel already has the control (by name - but you can modify this to use types, or literally anything you want.

Create a new project, and paste this in to the namespace block (I don't know what you'll name it. WindowsFormsApp1 maybe, or whatever).

I created everything dynamically so you don't need to mess with the designer to get it to work. It will log how many UC's are in the panel, so you know it's grabbing the existing one, and not creating a new one.

The key here is that with a UC, all you need to do is "BringToFront" and everything else is just handled for you. It will not create unneccessary ones.  I believe this is what you want:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Panel pnlMain;
    Panel pnlSelect;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //You will already have all of this - this is just to make a minimal-complete example without the designer.
        pnlSelect = new Panel();
        pnlMain = new Panel();
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { pnlSelect, pnlMain });
        pnlSelect.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        pnlMain.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        pnlSelect.Width = (int)(this.Width * 0.2);
        pnlMain.Width = this.Width - pnlSelect.Width - 25;
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = i.ToString();
            btn.Text = i.ToString();
            pnlSelect.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Location = new Point(btn.Location.X, btn.Height * i + 5);
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        }
        //just to see a difference
        pnlMain.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        UserControl oCon = (from Control uc in pnlMain.Controls where uc.GetType() == typeof(UserControl) && uc.Name == btn.Name select uc).FirstOrDefault();
        if(oCon == null)
        {
            oCon = new UserControl();
            oCon.Name = btn.Name;
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(oCon);
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = oCon.Name;
            oCon.Controls.Add(lbl);
            //just to see a difference
            oCon.BackColor = Color.Blue;                
        }
        oCon.BringToFront();
        Console.WriteLine("pnlMain has: {0} Children.", pnlMain.Controls.Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, So i understand what you have there..
You have the buttons that when clicked, check if a UC exists with that buttons name and if not, create a new instance of the UC with lbl as button name which is control name.
If UC DOES exist, just bring to front.

SO why is this not working for me.  For testing purposes i put the name of the UC in my oCon string.
This opens the usercontrol correctly, but it keeps coming aback with oCon == NULL so creates more instances of it! :(

I added code in Update to question

Comment: @GlennAngel Ok, so the labels, text, etc is just so you can see stuff more easily (that things are changing)... Don't get too caught up in the content - your UC's will have their own unique content. The labels are irrelevant. Basically, you need to convert all of your forms into UserControls. It will take some work.  Alternatively, you could use an MDI (Multiple-Document Interface). If converting to UserControls is too much work, it may be an easier solution...So, for clarity, frmpackmenu et al need to be UserControls for this to work, not forms.

Comment: thanks for the repsonse, i have converted the forms to user controls be changing the class part " public partial class MainPage : Form" to "public partial class MainPage : UserControl"
They had some errors but are fixed and running fine.  I did this before i started implememnting your solution